# Create dart package for AngularDart

Tags: angular-dart

Using: dart 2.0.0

How do you create components for AngularDart?

I have with no luck, looked at https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components

I have done the following steps:

1. stagehand package-simple
2. added `export` to dart file with `library <packageName>;`
3. referenced the package in `pubspec.yaml`

   You must have a dependency on `build_runner` in `pubspec.yaml`.
   dev_dependencies:
     build_runner: >=0.8.10 <2.0.0
   You must have a dependency on `build_web_compilers` in `pubspec.yaml`.
   dev_dependencies:
     build_web_compilers: >=0.3.6 <0.5.0

   Please check the following imports:
   `import 'package:<...>template.dart''

I have tried to build the package with:

```
 webdev build
webdev could not run for this project.
You must have a dependency on `build_runner` in `pubspec.yaml`.
# pubspec.yaml
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: >=0.8.10 <2.0.0
You must have a dependency on `build_web_compilers` in `pubspec.yaml`.
# pubspec.yaml
dev_dependencies:
  build_web_compilers: >=0.3.6 <0.5.0
```

Note: Using just a simple class, it works - but not with web components:

This works:

```
class Awesome {
  bool get isAwesome => true;
}
```

This do not:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-card',
  templateUrl: 'my_card.html',
  styleUrls: ['my_card.css'],
  directives: [coreDirectives],
  // pipes: [commonPipes],
)
class MyCard {
  var cardstring = 'My Card - string';
}
```

When using it in anyway:

```
<my-card></my-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Dart project with pubspec.yaml (name, SDK constraints, Angular dependency).
Create a component file in `lib/my_component.dart` and `lib/my_component.html`.
That's it.
Alternatively you can put the component in `lib/src/my_component.*` with a file like `lib/my_components.dart`

```
export 'src/my_component.dart';
```

In you application project where you want to use the component package, add a dependency to your component package.

```
dependencies:
  angular: ^5.0.0
  my_components: ^0.1.0 # requires the package to be published to pub.dartlang.ort
  # alternatively (without publishing
  my_components:
    path: ../my_components
  # or if checked in to GitHub
  my_components:
    git: git://github.com/myaccount/my_components.git
```

See also https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies

Then you use the component by importing it

```
import 'package:my_components/my_components.dart';

@Component(
  selector: ....
  directives: [MyComponent],
  ...
)
class AppComponent {}
```

and add it to AppComponent (or any other components) HTML as

```
<my-component></my-component>
```